# What would the next step in an approval process be after "formally"

Tags: single-word-requests

When a form is run through an approval process, I want to create statuses for different stages of said approval.

For now, I have the following:

- Requested (Initial request was submitted)
- Approved formally (Request has been checked formally, meaning that required data is present and it doesn't contain any formal errors, such as wrong date format, too few characters, etc.)
- Approved ...?
- Approved financially (The request can be paid for)
- Resolved (Request has been processed)
- Closed (Request has been shipped)

What I am missing is a word for *the requests content has been checked it makes sense, is correct in the domain and can be implemented/resolved*.

I was thinking about "Approved contextually" but that doesn't quite sound as what I want.

Comment: So someone has said "The request is clear, and it is something we want - let's get a budget for it?" Which role or committee is responsible for saying that?

Comment: There is something called "KeyUsers" in there, who say that the request should be done but they still have to get the approval of the financial guys before it can be done. Are you thinking about something like *"Approved by KeyUser"*?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about something like that. You have "Approved financially"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bump 'Approved formally' into your ? spot and use *validated* in its place.

This is a pre-existing term in web design - when you submit a form online, it is validated: the page checks you haven't used numbers in your name, that your e-mail address has an @ in it etc. In other words, it just checks for format errors and doesn't evaluate anything beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

These terms all describe the completed part of the process. That consistency is admirable but another approach to get out of this bind is to label them by what the *next* step is.

i.e. if this is about the people in charge of your purse-strings, *Pending Budget Approval* (or just *Pending Budget*)

If this is about waiting for a customer to pay before doing the work: *Pending payment*.

Answer (score 1):

In some organisations, an item will be prioritised by Subject Matter Experts or customers, to indicate how much they want this task done - or that this item meets some minimum level of desirability.

This will be evaluated against the cost and budget to determine if it will be done (and when).

In such a case *Prioritised* (or *Prioritized*, to taste) would be an appropriate name for this step.